# How to use Callbacks with echarts4r in a Shiny App

Tags: r, shiny, callback, tidyverse, echarts4r

I am looking to retrieve the user selected information in echarts4r objects in the server, for server side logic. I am looking to use the callbacks `id_clicked_data`, `id_mouseover_data`, etc found here https://echarts4r.john-coene.com/reference/echarts4r-shiny.html.

In the toy app (below) I am looking to return the value of the clicked country on the map to return the value to the screen via the `outpt_map_country` object. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

I have tried with variations of `input$outpt_map_country_clicked_data` but the solutions is alluding me.

```
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)
library(countrycode)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  echarts4rOutput('outpt_map'),
  verbatimTextOutput('outpt_map_country'),
  tableOutput('out_cns')
)


cns <- data.frame(
  country = countrycode::codelist$country.name.en
) %>% 
  mutate(value   = round(runif(length(country), 1, 5), 6))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$outpt_map <- renderEcharts4r({
    
    cns %>% 
      e_charts(country) %>% 
      e_map(value) 
  })
  
  output$outpt_map_country <- renderPrint({
    
    input$outpt_map_country_clicked_data
    
  })
  
  output$out_cns <- renderTable({
    
    cns
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I think it was a copy/paste error. Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback you are trying to use is `id_clicked_data`, but you give the id of the print output instead of the map output.

Replace `input$outpt_map_country_clicked_data` by `input$outpt_map_clicked_data` and it works:

```
library(shiny)
library(echarts4r)
library(countrycode)
library(dplyr)


ui <- fluidPage(
  echarts4rOutput('outpt_map'),
  verbatimTextOutput('outpt_map_country'),
  tableOutput('out_cns')
)


cns <- data.frame(
  country = countrycode::codelist$country.name.en
) %>% 
  mutate(value   = round(runif(length(country), 1, 5), 6))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$outpt_map <- renderEcharts4r({
    
    cns %>% 
      e_charts(country) %>% 
      e_map(value) 
  })
  
  output$outpt_map_country <- renderPrint({
    
    input$outpt_map_clicked_data
    
  })
  
  output$out_cns <- renderTable({
    
    cns
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```